# Lack of Memory for picturebox

Tags: c#, image, memory-leaks, switch-statement, picturebox

I create mini games which work with picture box for switch image. I using this for switch. I usually using max 30 images for app.

**Definitions:**

```
class UnikatniHodnoty
{
    public static List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
    public static List<string> uhodnuteObrazky = new List<string>();
    public static bool security = false;
    public static string pocetPokusu;
    public static string casNaObrazky;
    public static string casNaTah;
    public static string bodyKVitestvi;
}
```

**This is my script for loading image from files:**

```
class nacteniSouboru
{
    string obrazky;
    string zadniKarta;
    string zadniStrana;
    public string hledanyObrazek;
    public List<string> obrazkyList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> obrazkyListControl = new List<string>();

    public nacteniSouboru()
    {
        // Cesty k souborům
        var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        obrazky = currentDirectory + @"\vse\";
        zadniStrana = currentDirectory + @"\zadniStrana\";

        // Základní hodnota
        zadniKarta = "";
    }

    public void nacteniObrazku()
    {
        var listOfFiles = new List<string>();
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(obrazky);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            listOfFiles.Add(fileName);

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; obrazkyList.Count < 15; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(0, listOfFiles.Count - 1);
            if (!obrazkyList.Contains(listOfFiles[index]))
            {
                obrazkyList.Add(listOfFiles[index]);
                obrazkyListControl.Add(listOfFiles[index]);
            }
        }  
    }

    public void zobrazeniObrazku()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Button bTn in UnikatniHodnoty.buttonList)
        {
            if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();

            bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(obrazkyList[i++]);
        }
    }

    public void nacteniHledanehoObrazku(PictureBox picture)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        foreach (string obrazky in UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky)
            obrazkyListControl.Remove(obrazky);

        int index = random.Next(0, obrazkyListControl.Count - 1);
        hledanyObrazek = obrazkyListControl[index];

        if (picture.BackgroundImage != null)
            picture.BackgroundImage.Dispose();

        picture.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(obrazkyListControl[index]);
    }

    public void nacteniZadniStrany()
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(zadniStrana);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            zadniKarta = fileName;

        foreach (Button bTn in UnikatniHodnoty.buttonList)
        {
            if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();

            bTn.Text = "";
            bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(zadniKarta);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me how can i clean lack of memory after every switch images because call this fuction every 30s.

**This is script for switch images:**

```
    private void obrazek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bTn = new Button();
        bTn = (Button)sender;
        timeTah.Enabled = false;

        switch (bTn.Name)
        {
            case "picture_0_0":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null) 
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[0]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[0] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[0]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_0_1":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[1]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[1] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[1]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_0_2":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[2]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[2] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[2]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_0_3":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[3]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[3] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[3]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_0_4":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[4]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[4] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[4]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_1_0":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[5]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[5] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[5]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_1_1":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[6]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[6] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[6]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_1_2":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[7]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[7] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[7]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_1_3":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[8]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[8] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[8]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_1_4":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[9]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[9] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[9]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_2_0":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[10]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[10] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[10]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_2_1":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[11]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[11] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[11]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_2_2":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[12]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[12] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[12]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_2_3":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[13]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[13] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[13]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
            case "picture_2_4":
                if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
                    bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
                bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(soubor.obrazkyList[14]);
                if (soubor.obrazkyList[14] == soubor.hledanyObrazek)
                {
                    UnikatniHodnoty.uhodnuteObrazky.Add(soubor.obrazkyList[14]);
                    uspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                }
                else
                    neuspechNaObrazku(sender, e);
                break;
        }
        soubor.nacteniZadniStrany();
    }
```

**Problem:**

Game still crashed after loading image or if i added some new images to file. And if games crashed so its written only crash that "Lack of Memory" nothing more and not where. Please help.

**Error:**

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory 

    in System.Drawing.Image.FromFile (String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement) 

    in System.Drawing.Image.FromFile (String filename) 

    in gameCards.soubory.nacteniSouboru.zobrazeniObrazku () d: \ Program \ gameCards \ gameCards \ files \ nacteniSouboru.cs: line 60 

    in gameCards.gameCard.spustit_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) in d: \ Program \ gameCards \ gameCards \ gameCards.cs: line 49 

    in System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick (EventArgs e) 

    in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick (EventArgs e) 

    in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp (MouseEventArgs mevent) 

    in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp (Message & m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks) 

    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (Message & m) 

    in System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (Message & m) 

    in System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (Message & m) 

    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage (Message & m) 

    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (Message & m) 

    in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback (IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

public void zobrazeniObrazku()  // When i use this code so it sent me upper errors.
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Button bTn in UnikatniHodnoty.buttonList)
    {
        if (bTn.BackgroundImage != null)
            bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose();

        bTn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(obrazkyList[i++]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might make it easier for us if you translate the variable names to English, so it makes more sense to us. At what line does the error occur? Anyways, you should probably load all picture_x_y images into a list and reuse them, rather than loading one again and again, each time you need a new image.

Comment: You seem to assign an image to a button but never dispose of it. Add a `if (bTn.BackgroundImage!=null) bTn.BackgroundImage.Dispose;` before you assign a new image!

Comment: I tried it "TaW" and after i told you if work it

Comment: TaW -> Problem is not fixed with this. Game still crashed.

Comment: I added debug with exception to first post and i added your dispose to script TaW., can you check it please.

Comment: allow that you might have more than one thing wrong.  In x86, I can assign an ImageFrom file only 109 times before OOM.  Disposing as @TaW suggests solves that (currently at 1700+).  The language issue makes it **very** hard to tell, but the error looks like it originates from `soubor.nacteniZadniStrany();`.  It is almost certainly a dispose related issue which you may be able to see in TaskManager under GDI objects (mine is steady at 38 with 3500+ image assignments).

Comment: The way you added the dispose seems ok, but there may be more wrong, as Plutonix suggests. The error points to 'zobrazeniObrazku', which is not shown..

Comment: @TaW thats in the first code block

Comment: You are right (ffox's search didn't see it, strange..) and it looks ok, too. try to watch the gdi objects in task manager to make sure it is the problem!

Comment: in my first post i using four block for all scripts or debug. In first block is only definitions. Second block have all informations  about function around files and images with "zobrazeniObrazku". This function is in second block i saw it. Third block is script for switching image in main instance in program and four block is only debug. Line 60 is this function "zobrazeniObrazku" and line 49 is call in main instance this function "soubor.zobrazeniObrazku".

Comment: I added to last block information about function "zobrazeniObrazku" and this code have important dependence on function in second block where it name as "nacteniObrazku()";

Comment: I looked to task manager where is value for my app (Procesor - > 11%, RAM - > 22,1 MB, Disk -> 0%, Network - > 0%, PID - > 6660). I havent this problem for my main pc, but only for my notebook where i using app for data projector. Tomorrow i can check GDI object in task manager for my notebook. And i using max 30 images for app.

Comment: can you tell me some news please about this problem?